# Phonegap - mysql data

Tags: mysql, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm just looking into using PhoneGap (Cordova3) and I'm basically looking at creating a screen that pulls in data from MySQL as soon as it loads and then be able to click on the results that will then load in another page (with the mysql details etc)

Am I right in thinking I'd need to use jQuery?

I've seen jQuery mobile, but I don't want to load the whole database resultset.

So for example:

Categories to load when app starts:

```
Music Travel Lifestyle
```

Click on `Music` it will then query the database and display a list based on the results.

What is the best approach for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use jquery and code something like:

```
<a href="#" onClick="queryData('Music');">Music</a>
<a href="#" onClick="queryData('Travel');">Travel</a>
<a href="#" onClick="queryData('LifeStyle');">LifeStyle</a>
```

and then a function:

```
function queryData(value) {
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    data: { search: value }, 
    async: true, 
    crossDomain: true, 
    url: "remoteURI.php", 
    success: function(data){ 
           //show results in a div
    } 
  }); 
}
```